# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12400 into shape (1,4)

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, spyder, 3d-model

I'm Constructing 3d model from 2d images, I tried a lot but cannot fix this error.

```
def reprojection_loss_function(opt_variables, points_2d, num_pts):
    P = opt_variables[0:12].reshape(3,4)
    point_3d = opt_variables[12:].reshape((len(points_2d[0]),4))
```

Comment: Please give more information. Specifically, the input and the traceback would be useful.

Comment: inputs are 20 snaps(images) of endoscopy video

Comment: I want to create a 3D model(motion) of these images.

Comment: No, that's not the kind of information that we need.  The source of the variables doesn't help (they could be random numbers for all we care).  The immediate problem is with the `shape` of the `opt_variables` array.  Do you know what we mean by `shape`?  Or what `reshape` is supposed to do?